# EntityPrefetch does not speed up EntityClass queries

Tags: entity

For example, we can run

```
EntityPrefetch["Element"]
```

to prefetch information related to Entity type "Element". And it shows on my computer

[image]

However, queries on EntityClass of "Element" still needs a lot more time for the first time query like below.

[image]

So it seems that `EntityPrefetch` does prefetch EntityClass data. How can I prefetch more complete data of an Entity type like "Element"?